# nested block and for loop in a Jinja template block

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Trying to use nested block and for loop in a Jinja template block setup.

```html
{% block main %}
<table>
<tr>
<td>user id</td>
<td>user sec level</td>
</tr>
    {% block main_nested_b scoped %}
    {%
    for user in list_users:
        t_id_user = str(user[0][0])
        t_sec_level = str(user[2][0])
    %}
<tr>
<td>
<a href='/usersEdit?id_user={{ t_id_user }}' class='onwhite'>edit</a>
</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock main_nested_b %}
{% endblock main %}
</table>
```

Error message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 't_id_user'
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't treat Jinja syntax as Python syntax. It's not the same thing. Keep your [`for` tag](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) separate from [assignment (`set`) tags](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#assignments):

```html
    {% for user in list_users %}
        {% set t_id_user = user[0][0] %}
        {% set t_sec_level = user[2][0] %}
```

Note that there isn't even a `:` at the end of the `for ... in ...` syntax! Also you don't need to call `str()` here, leave that to Jinja to convert to strings for you; anywhere you use `{{ t_id_user }}` or `{{ t_sec_level }}` the value will be converted to a string anyway.

Here is the complete template:

```html
<table>
{% block main %}
    {% block main_nested_b scoped %}
    {% for user in list_users %}
        {% set t_id_user = user[0][0] %}
        {% set t_sec_level = user[2][0] %}
<tr>
<td>
<a href='/usersEdit?id_user={{ t_id_user }}' class='onwhite'>edit</a>
</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock main_nested_b %}
{% endblock main %}
</table>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked. On part I left out that is within that for loop that I'm getting an error on still. Please see my edit of code above with `if (len(....` statement.

Comment: Sorry, but a suggested edit should really not be used to reply. If you can't find a way to format something in a comment, perhaps use a `gist` or consider posting a new question with the new error you now have.

Comment: @ScotterMonkey: and there is no need to do your `if` test. Just use the [`truncate` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#truncate): `{{ t_email_show | truncate(18, False, '', 0) }}`.

Comment: @ScotterMonkey: or just use `{{ t_email_show[:18] }}` *without testing*; provided `t_email_show` is a string, then slicing a shorter string will not produce an error just because you asked for 18 characters in the slice.

Comment: I want to thank you because I learned a huge amount today from you; important lessons that have already helped a lot and will help more in the future as I build this app.